# Constrained Multi-Linear Regression using Gekko

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression, gekko

I have a multilinear regression problem where I have the prior information about the range of the output (dependent variable y) - The prediction must always lie in that range.

I want to find the coefficients (upper and lower bound) of each feature (independent variables) in order to make the linear regression model restricted to the desired range of output.

For example, I want to apply this solution on sklearn.datasets.load_boston where I know that the price of the house will be in the range of [10, 40] (the actual min and max values of y are [5,50]).

In the following example, my objective is **10 < yp < 40** and based on this I want to find the min and max bound of all the coefficients

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO

# Loading the dataset
x, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)

c  = m.Array(m.FV, x.shape[1]+1) #array of parameters and intercept

for ci in c:
    ci.STATUS = 1 #calculate fixed parameter
    ci.LOWER  = 1 #constraint: lower limit
    ci.UPPER  = 0 #constraint: lower limit

#Define variables
xd = m.Array(m.Param,x.shape[1])
for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    xd[i].value = x[i]
yd = m.Param(y); yp = m.Var()

#Equation of Linear Functions
y_pred = c[0]*xd[0]+\
         c[1]*xd[1]+\
         c[2]*xd[2]+\
         c[3]*xd[3]+\
         c[4]*xd[4]+\
         c[5]*xd[5]+\
         c[6]*xd[6]+\
         c[7]*xd[7]+\
         c[8]*xd[8]+\
         c[9]*xd[9]+\
         c[10]*xd[10]+\
         c[11]*xd[11]+\
         c[12]*xd[12]+\
         c[13]

#Inequality Constraints
yp = m.Var(lb=5,ub=40)
m.Equation(yp==y_pred)

#Minimize difference between actual and predicted y
m.Minimize((yd-yp)**2)

#Solve
m.solve(disp=True)

#Retrieve parameter values
a = [i.value[0] for i in c]

print(a)
```

The listed code either gives me a solution not found error. Can you point out what I'm doing wrong here, or am I missing something important? Also, how can I get both the Upper and Lower bound of c for all independent variables?

Comment: Here is a comparison of Gekko with other regression methods in Python: https://apmonitor.com/pds/index.php/Main/LinearRegression The scale-up is important for large-scale problems. Gekko allows constrained and nonlinear optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `IMODE=2` for regression mode. There are a few modifications such as `x[:,i]` to load the data and `ci.LOWER=0` as the lower bounds and `ci.UPPER=1` as the upper bound.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
# Loading the dataset
x, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
n = x.shape[1]
c  = m.Array(m.FV, n+1) #array of parameters and intercept
for ci in c:
    ci.STATUS = 1 #calculate fixed parameter
    ci.LOWER  = 0 #constraint: lower limit
    ci.UPPER  = 1 #constraint: lower limit
#Load data
xd = m.Array(m.Param,n)
for i in range(n):
    xd[i].value = x[:,i]
yd = m.Param(y)
#Equation of Linear Functions
yp = m.Var(lb=5,ub=40)
m.Equation(yp==m.sum([c[i]*xd[i] \
               for i in range(n)]) + c[13])
#Minimize difference between actual and predicted y
m.Minimize((yd-yp)**2)
#Regression mode
m.options.IMODE=2
#APOPT solver
m.options.SOLVER = 1
#Solve
m.solve(disp=True)
#Retrieve parameter values
a = [i.value[0] for i in c]
print(a)
```

The solution to this constrained problem is obtained with the IPOPT or APOPT (slightly faster).

```
 Number of state variables:    7604
 Number of total equations: -  7590
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    14
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Model Parameter Estimation with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  5.60363E+04  1.25000E+00
    1  1.87753E+05  6.66134E-16
    2  3.06630E+04  9.99201E-16
    3  3.06630E+04  3.84187E-16
    5  3.06630E+04  1.35308E-16
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.48429999999999995 sec
 Objective      :  30662.976306748842
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
 

[0.0, 0.11336851243, 0.0, 1.0, 0.43491543768, 
 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.037613878067,
 0.0, 1.0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just realised, I forgot to add the Gekko initialisation part which includes the IMODE=2 in the post. One question, what is the significance of setting ci.LOWER=0  and ci.UPPER=1?

Comment: Your original code has `ci.LOWER  = 1 #constraint: lower limit` and `ci.UPPER  = 0` as the upper limit. These are lower and upper bounds on the `ci` parameters. You can remove these if they are unbounded.